# Is there a term analogous to factoring, for addition?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, arithmetic

e.g. $12$ can be expressed as a product of its factors: $2 \times 6, 3 \times 4$. The composites can be decomposed further.

$12$ can also be expressed as a sum of its *`something`s*: $1+11, 2+10, 3+9, ...$. The non-$1$'s can be decomposed further.

It seems to me that if primes are the atoms of multiplication, then $1$ is the atom of addition. (BTW and maybe the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic* should be called the *Fundamental Theorem of Multiplication*)

Comment: Maybe --- partition?

Comment: The ways to write a number as sum of numbers (with additional properties perhaps) is investigated under the term *partition*.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the word you're looking for is partition. This is fundamental to additive number theory.

Comment: Arithmetic progressions

Comment: Just my two cents: I disagree with your BTW. a positive integer $n$ can be broken down into a unique partition of 1's, but that's nowhere near as interesting as the fact that one $n$ can be broken down to a whole bunch of prime factors but $n + 1$ might be the square of a prime. In my opinion.

Comment: I think writing a number in base $B$ might be the additive equivalent of factoring.

Comment: @RobertSoupe my BTW just meant that FTA is about multiplication, not addition, so "arithmetic" is overbroad. I don't quite understand - you're saying that FTA *does* involve addition, because $n$ and $n+1$ have different prime factors? It's still about mutliplication. Analogously, $n$ and $nm$ also have different 1 partitions, yet it's still about addition. (I agree *prime* atoms are far more interesting than *1* atoms.)

Comment: Could someone write up "partition" as an answer, so I can accept it, please? It makes it easier for future readers.

Comment: Well... we could get very philosophical with this, since multiplication is repeated addition.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right, including your BTW. Actually, the notion of *prime* and *irreducible* can be defined in any commutative monoid. 
The two cases you consider correspond to free commutative monoids.

**Details**. The monoid $(\mathbb{N}-\{0\}, \times)$ is a [free commutative monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid#The_free_commutative_monoid) over the basis consisting of the prime numbers. That is, every positive integer has a unique decomposition as a product of prime numbers. 
Similarly, $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ is a free monoid with basis $\{1\}$, the only prime element. Still with addition, $(\mathbb{N}^k, +)$ is a free commutative monoid with a basis consisting of $k$ primes. For instance, the basis of $(\mathbb{N}^3, +)$ is $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding the terminology

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Terms):

> The numbers or the objects to be added in general addition are collectively referred to as the **terms**, the **addends** or the **summands**;

Apparently, one can even use the designation augend to distinguish between 1st and subsequent summand ($\underbrace{1}_{\text{augend}}+\underbrace{11}_{\text{addend}}$).

> Some authors call the first addend the **augend**.

In your example:

> $12$ can also be expressed as a sum of its terms/addends/summands: $1+11,2+10,3+9,\dots$. The non-$1$'s can be decomposed further.